# IE7 cuts-off input fields in a form

Tags: internet-explorer-7, forms

All other browsers, including IE8, render the form correctly, except IE7; I assume IE6 exibits same problem.

IE7 cuts-off, shrinks the form, and shows about 5% of the input fields;

I removed all css formatting but not change; I have applied several related fixes without success; help or direction as to where to find related information or know fixes is welcome since it has consumed much time without success; thanks;

html is included below;

```
<pre>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>IMM log-in</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" name="form" id="form" action="/imm/login.htm" style=
  "font-family:arial;font-size:9pt;padding:5px;table.horizontal-align:left;display:inline;">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <table>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><label>log-in ID</label><span class="required">*</span></td>
                  <td align="left">
                      <input type="text" name="name" id="form_name" value="" size=
                      "20" style="width:100%;" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td align="left"><label>password</label><span class="required">*</span></td>
                  <td align="left">
                      <input type="password" name="password" id="form_password"
                      value="" size="20" style="width:100%;" />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            <table class="buttons" id="form-buttons">
              <tbody>
                <tr class="buttons">
                  <td class="buttons"><input type="submit" name="ok" id="form_ok" value=
                  " OK " /></td>
                  <td class="buttons"><input type="submit" name="cancel" id="form_cancel"
                  value="Cancel" /></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>

</pre>
```

Comment: I'm having a difficult time imagining what you mean by "cuts off". Can you provide an example URL or a screen shot?

Comment: I'm a new registered user and have no credits for upload an image; the form is 'compressed' and the two input fields show about 5% or less starting from the left cut off the right side, ie. does not show the remaining 95% of the two input fields.

Comment: Note that in I remove style="width:100%;" on the input fields, these now show but are on unequal in size; if I surround these fields with a fieldset the problem remains; I have tried bracketing div and span without success also;

Comment: partially solved this problem by replacing style="width: 100%" with  style="width: 150px"

It is not a great solution; in textareas IE7 exhibits the same problem, field shrinks, affects other input fields also, and same solution is less than elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this thing `position:relative`